# Pocketsphinx keeps giving the same output

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I'm checking out pocketsphinx and am getting the following output:

```
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
\
    -hmm ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k \
    -lm ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4.5000.DMP \
    -dict ../Pocketsphinx_Files/cmu07a.dic 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   yes     yes
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               ../Pocketsphinx_Files/cmu07a.dic
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4.5000.DMP
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      -1
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      -1
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
\
    -nfilt 20 \
    -lowerf 1 \
    -upperf 4000 \
    -wlen 0.025 \
    -transform dct \
    -round_filters no \
    -remove_dc yes \
    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
    -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
    -agc none \
    -cmn current \
    -cmninit 56,-3,1 \
    -varnorm no 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     56,-3,1
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-frate      100     100
-input_endian   little      little
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lifter     0       0
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.000000e+00
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      20
-remove_dc  no      yes
-round_filters  yes     no
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             0-12/13-25/26-38
-transform  legacy      dct
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   4.000000e+03
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wlen       0.025625    2.500000e-02

INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150 CI-sen, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0
INFO: dict.c(317): Allocating 137543 * 32 bytes (4298 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(332): Reading main dictionary: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/cmu07a.dic
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 1010 KiB for strings, 1664 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(335): 133436 words read
INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler dictionary: ../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(344): 11 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 60400 bytes (58 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(195): Allocated 60400 bytes (58 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5001, 2=436879, 3=418286
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5001 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   436879 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   418286 = LM.trigrams read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    37293 = LM.prob2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    14370 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    36094 = LM.prob3 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      854 = LM.tseg_base entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5001 = ascii word strings read
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 788 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 60 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 60 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 13428
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 457 root, 13300 non-root channels, 26 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: cmn.c(175): CMN: 82.59 -5.43 -3.63 -0.23 -1.42  0.08 -0.76  0.13 -0.47  0.09 -0.27  0.08 -0.14 
INFO: ngram_search.c(474): Resized backpointer table to 10000 entries
INFO: ngram_search.c(474): Resized backpointer table to 20000 entries
INFO: ngram_search.c(474): Resized backpointer table to 40000 entries
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1549):    35863 words recognized (13/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1551): 11031865 senones evaluated (3882/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1553): 16716461 channels searched (5881/fr), 1296966 1st, 962496 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1557):   102516 words for which last channels evaluated (36/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1560):  2070712 candidate words for entering last phone (728/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1562): fwdtree 3.92 CPU 0.138 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1565): fwdtree 3.92 wall 0.138 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 2 words
('', '000000000', -238874)         <------------ **output**
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(937):     2846 words recognized (1/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(939):     8523 senones evaluated (3/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(941):     2911 channels searched (1/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(943):     2911 words searched (1/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(945):       58 word transitions (0/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948): fwdflat 0.05 CPU 0.002 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(951): fwdflat 0.05 wall 0.002 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(1214): </s> not found in last frame, using <sil>.2840 instead
INFO: ngram_search.c(1266): lattice start node <s>.0 end node <sil>.2
INFO: ngram_search.c(1294): Eliminated 0 nodes before end node
INFO: ngram_search.c(1399): Lattice has 2 nodes, 1 links
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1365): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(<sil>:2:2840) = -12300564
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1403): Joint P(O,S) = -12300564 P(S|O) = 0
INFO: ngram_search.c(888): bestpath 0.00 CPU 0.000 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(891): bestpath 0.00 wall 0.000 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(430): TOTAL fwdtree 3.92 CPU 0.138 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(433): TOTAL fwdtree 3.92 wall 0.138 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(174): TOTAL fwdflat 0.05 CPU 0.002 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(177): TOTAL fwdflat 0.05 wall 0.002 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(317): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 CPU 0.000 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(320): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 wall 0.000 xRT
```

And the code I'm using is:

```
try:
    import pocketsphinx

except:
    import pocketsphinx as ps
    import sphinxbase

hmmd = "../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4wsj_sc_8k"
lmdir = "../Pocketsphinx_Files/hub4.5000.DMP"
dictp = "../Pocketsphinx_Files/cmu07a.dic"

if __name__=="__main__":
    wavFile = open("../temp/temp_output.wav","rb")

    speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp)

    wavFile.seek(44)

    speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)

    result = speechRec.get_hyp()

    print(result)
```

What am I doing wrong? Could it be that I'm not using the correct hmm, lm, dict? If so, how do I know which ones I should use and where should I get them?

Comment: Share the file you are trying to recognize

Comment: Here is a link to it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqt1rv8o2j4rmz5/temp_output.wav
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your file has wrong format. It must be 16khz 16bit mono MSWAV file. Your file is 44.1khz stereo.

Comment: And, for the best decoding accuracy it's better to use en-us generic acoustic model and en-us generic language model available in downloads.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev - Thanks! I'll try it out!

Is there a specific way you recomend to convert the file perhaps?